# how can i fix the installation of Koin in ktor/intellij

Tags: kotlin, ktor, koin

I'm trying to use install koin but it gives the following text when i hover over it.

> Type mismatch.
> Required:
> Plugin<TypeVariable(P), TypeVariable(B), TypeVariable(F)>
> Found:
> Koin.Feature

the code is as in the following:

```
import io.ktor.server.application.*
import org.koin.ktor.ext.Koin

fun Application.configureKoin(){
install(Koin){
    
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are trying to install a plugin, that's written for Ktor `1.*`, in a Ktor server with version `2.*`. To make it work you have to use Ktor server `1.*`, e.g `1.6.7`, or wait until plugin maintainers migrate to version `2.0.0`. [Here](https://ktor.io/docs/eap/migrating-2.html#server-package) you can find a list of incompatible changes and a migration guide for Ktor `2.0.0`.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue. Which version of the ktor plugin are you using?
I was using 2.0.0 beta and changed to 1.6.4 and it works now.
Can find it in the gradle.properties file.

Comment: this removed the error thank you

Answer (score 1):

Until the Ktor 2.0 plugin for Koin is added, you can use the solution below, which is taken from [here](https://github.com/InsertKoinIO/koin/issues/1257#issuecomment-1000856335) (credits to phucynwa). Also, you can track the [Pull request](https://%20https://github.com/InsertKoinIO/koin/pull/1266) here.

```
object KoinPlugin : ApplicationPlugin<Application, KoinApplication, Unit> {

   override val key: AttributeKey<Unit>
       get() = AttributeKey("Koin")

   override fun install(
       pipeline: Application,
       configure: KoinApplication.() -> Unit
   ) {
       val monitor = pipeline.environment.monitor
       val koinApplication = startKoin(appDeclaration = configure)
       monitor.raise(EventDefinition(), koinApplication)

       monitor.subscribe(ApplicationStopping) {
           monitor.raise(EventDefinition(), koinApplication)
           stopKoin()
           monitor.raise(EventDefinition(), koinApplication)
       }
   }
}
```

---

```
fun Application.installPlugins() {
   install(KoinPlugin)
}
```